# How to find normal vector of hyperplane in $n$-dimensional space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $p$ be a hyperplane in $n$-dimensional space. (So, $p$ is $\mathbf r \cdot \mathbf n = d$ for some $d \in \mathbb R$.)

In the case where $n=3$, we can pick any two non-parallel vectors $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ on $p$ and we have $\mathbf n = k(\mathbf u \times \mathbf v)$ (for some $k\neq 0$).

But in higher dimensions ($n>3$), given linearly independent vectors $\mathbf v_1$, $\mathbf v_2$, $\dots$, $\mathbf v_{n-1}$ on $p$, how might we similarly find $\mathbf n$?

Comment: So for $\mathbb{R}^n$, you find the normal to the $(n-1)$ dimensonial hyperplane by finding out two vectors on the hyperplane, say $(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, and find the normals as $\mathbf{n} = \mathbf{x} \times \mathbf{y}$; this is understood, right? In the question, I do not understand the role of the basis vectors $\mathbf{v}_1, ..., \mathbf{v}_{n-1}$, why should we care about them? If this is the only information you have, this certainly does not define a hyperplane.

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Multilinear_algebra)

Comment: It is determined in basically the same way. When $n=3$, the elements of $u\times v$ are given by the minors (with alternating signs) in the $3\times2$ matrix $\pmatrix{u&v}$. For a larger $n$, the elements of a vector $v_n$ orthogonal to the linear span of $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{n-1}$ are given by the signed minors of the $n\times(n-1)$ matrix $\pmatrix{v_1&v_2&\cdots&v_{n-1}}$. Now normalise $v_n$ to get a normal vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a parametrised vector of the hyperplane. In $n$ dimensions you have: $$p=\mathbf v_0+\lambda_1 \mathbf {v_1}+\lambda_2\mathbf {v_2} +\cdots+\lambda_{n-1}\mathbf{v_{n-1}}$$

Where $\lambda_k$ are $n-1$ scalars of the field the space is over.

Then all normal vectors $\vec n$ have the property that

$$(p-\mathbf {v_0})\cdot \vec n=0$$

Thus, $$\begin{align}0 &=(\lambda_1 \mathbf {v_1}+\lambda_2\mathbf {v_2} +\cdots+\lambda_{n-1}\mathbf{v_{n-1}})\cdot\vec n\\
&=\left(\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf {v_1} & \mathbf {v_2} &\cdots &\mathbf {v_{n-1}}\end{pmatrix}\vec \lambda \right)^T\vec n\\
&=(\vec\lambda)^T\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf {v_1}^T\\ \mathbf {v_2}^T\\ \vdots \\ \mathbf {v_{n-1}}^T\end{pmatrix}\vec n
\end{align}$$

And since this must be true for any $\vec \lambda$

$$\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf {v_1}^T\\ \mathbf {v_2}^T\\ \vdots \\ \mathbf {v_{n-1}}^T\end{pmatrix}\vec n=\mathbf 0$$

So $\vec n$ is exactly the kernel (nullspace)

$$\operatorname{ker} \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf {v_1}^T\\ \mathbf {v_2}^T\\ \vdots \\ \mathbf {v_{n-1}}^T\end{pmatrix}$$

or the cokernel (left nullspace) of the matrix of any set of vectors that form a basis for the [direction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space#Affine_subspaces_and_parallelism) of the affine-subspace $p$

$$\operatorname{coker}\big(\begin{matrix}\mathbf {v_1}& \mathbf {v_2}&\cdots&\mathbf {v_{n-1}}\end{matrix}\big)$$

Comment: Interestingly wikipedia section [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)#Hypersurfaces_in_n-dimensional_space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)#Hypersurfaces_in_n-dimensional_space) needs to be corrected. Archived current webpage [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20230812053416/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_%28geometry%29)

Answer (score 0):

Collect the $v_k$ vectors into a matrix
$$\eqalign{
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\rank#1{\op{rank}\LR{#1}}
\def\mc#1{\left[\begin{array}{r|r}#1\end{array}\right]}
V &=  \mc{v_1&v_2&\cdots&v_{n-1}} \in \bbR{n\times(n-1)} \\
}$$
and calculate its *Hat Matrix*
$$\eqalign{
H &= V\LR{V^TV}^{-1}\,V^T \\
}$$
Notice that
$$\eqalign{
\LR{I-H}V = 0 \qiq \LR{I-H}v_k = 0  \\
}$$
but for almost any other (i.e. random) vector $\,r\in\bbR{n}\,$ one obtains
$$\eqalign{
v_n &= \LR{I-H}r \\
}$$
which is orthogonal to every column of $V$
$$\eqalign{
v_n^Tv_k &= r^T\LR{I-H}v_k = 0 \\
}$$
$\sf NB\!:$ The Hat Matrix can be expressed using the pseudoinverse as
$\,H = VV^+$

and thus $\LR{I-H}$ is an ortho-projector into the nullspace of $V$